# php How to use Array elements in declaring a dynamic array (I don't know how to better word it)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have loaded SQL data into a bunch of arrays. I would like to use those array to create one big multidimensional array.

```
for ($h=0; $h<=count($siteName); $h++){

    for ($x=0; $x<=count($pluginNames); $x++)
    {
        for ($y=0; $y<=count($wpvData); $y++)
        {
            $plugData = array($siteName[$h]=>array($pluginNames=>array($pluginNames[$x],$vData[$y],$wpvData[$y],$row[$y])));
        } 
    } 
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BJANSDJNAS.php on line 124

Warning: Illegal offset type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BJANSDJNAS.php on line 124
```

Line 124 = $plugData array line.

Is this even possible?

Is there a better way to do this all together?

My goal is to store a bunch of data related to a website in a multidimensional array so I can display it in html divs. Basically I have a wordpress site and I would like to manage the plugins with a nice GUI via html.

Comment: What do you mean by `array($pluginNames=>array(...))`? `$pluginNames` is an array, how can it be the key in an associative array?

Comment: The first error message means that one of the arrays doesn't have an element number 0. Are your original arrays indexed or associative? Maybe you should use `foreach` instead of `for`.

Comment: pluginNames holds all the names for the plugins.... I want the name of each plugin to have a its own set of data. Wouldn't I use the name at index whatever for the key? What I am doing may be very wrong Thats why came here for help

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably something like this:

```
$plugData = array();
foreach ($siteName as $site) {
    $plugData[$site] = array();
    foreach ($pluginNames as $plugin)
        $plugData[$site][$plugin] = array();
        foreach ($wpvData as $y => $wpv) {
            $plugData[$site][$plugin][] = array(
                'plugin' => $plugin,
                'vdata' => $vdata[$y],
                'wpv' => $wpv,
                'row' => $row[$y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the syntax for adding an element to an array is `$arrayname[] =`; `$arrayname =` simply replaces the whole array, it's not something you usually want in a loop.

Comment: I tried this and it resulted in : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BJANSDJNAS.php on line 121
var_dump ==== array(0) { }

Comment: It was the start of the foreach. I switched it to a different variable and it worked kind of.

Comment: There are 3 foreaches, I wanted to know which one. Anyway, the error means that the variable in the `foreach` isn't actually an array.

Comment: The variable `$siteName` is singular -- is it one site name or an array of site names? Maybe there's another variable `$siteNames` that you should be looping over? Without seeing more of your program, I have to make assumptions based on the original code, even though it's broken.

Comment: It was the FIRST foreach loop. And I changed siteName to tableName which is another variable I am using to hold the same data, siteName is created within a while loop it might get destroyed after the execution.

Comment: Your answer is putting me in the right direction so I +1 it. How can I reference indices of the Big Array. Eg: I want $plugData[$site[0]][$plugin[0]][$vData[0]]

Comment: `$plugData[$site][$plugin][$n]`

Comment: $n = whatever number I want?

Comment: Yes. You could also make that dimension an associative array, I just didn't know what to use as the key.

Comment: echo "$plugData[$site][$plugin][$vData[0]]"; this will display data but I wanted the first site in $sites and the first plugin in $plugin etc...

Comment: The variable names don't matter, you can use anything there. I'm just describing the structure of the array.